# how to achieve a listview like Gmail in andorid 5.0?

Tags: android, listview, pull-to-refresh

i want to make a pull-to-refresh listview, and i use the android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout,bus also i want to the item of listview can swipe left or right. like the gmail in android 5.0. who can help me? sample or code. or tell me how to do it. really really thx!

Answer (score -2):

You may refer to this sample application [Swipe_list_item_To_Delete](https://github.com/krishjlk/android-listview-swipe-delete-example-sample-tuorial) You may use ListView to list your data items which are got from the db or server. Then modify the getSwipeItem() method in the MainActivity of the example, as follows, if you are deleting the item from the list onSwipe()

```
@Override
public void getSwipeItem(boolean isRight, int position) {
    [List_Of_Items].remove(position);
    [Your_Adapter].notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And refer following Github sample [Pull-to_RefreshListView](https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView) for pull to refresh list view